# Is there a way to set the starting read line in vbscript?

Tags: vbscript, readline, filesystemobject

I have a text file and it has more than 85k lines
Is there a way to set the starting line? For example; I've already read and write the lines 1-10 to other file and want to get a value in line 12 to add it in the last line that I wrote. I want to read only the line 12.

> 1. Text/Sample/1/GetValue/12
> 2. Text/Sample/2/GetValue/11
> 3. Text/Sample/3/GetValue/10
> 4. Text/Sample/4/GetValue/9
> 5. Text/Sample/5/GetValue/8
> 6. Text/Sample/6/GetValue/7
> 7. Text/Sample/7/GetValue/6
> 8. Text/Sample/8/GetValue/5
> 9. Text/Sample/9/GetValue/4
> 10. Text/Sample/10/GetValue/3
> 11. Text/Sample/11/GetValue/2
> 12. Text/Sample/12/GetValue/1

Comment: Reading/writing files doesn't work that way on computers.

Comment: @Edss Check my answer !

Comment: Thanks @Hackoo; But I've already found a solution using Readall and work on Split and Do Loop

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The TextStream object provides sequential forward reading only. See the Docs for [.Skip](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s06h7b2w(v=vs.84).aspx), [.SkipLine](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/092z1463(v=vs.84).aspx), [.Read](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7w5tbs5z(v=vs.84).aspx), [.ReadLine](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/skwz6sz4(v=vs.84).aspx), and [.ReadAll](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dz7ffsba(v=vs.84).aspx).

So you have to skip/read to the desired position, or do some [Mid](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wffts6k3(v=vs.84).aspx) string work on the full content (.Readall) of the file.

Comment: I'm currently using skipline but still not enough, thanks for the advice! :)

Comment: If you want to read a specific line(say 12th), just use the skipline method 11 times(may be in a loop) and read the 12th line. What code have you written thus far?Post it here so that we can point out the mistake(s).

Comment: Is there no other way other than skipline?

For i = 1 To 10
 iOpen.SkipLine
Next

Comment: @Edss - define "still not enough". Did you consider .ReadAll?

Comment: @Ekkehard.Horner Like, It would be much faster if I can set the starting readline to 12 instead of skipping 11 lines.

Comment: Not sure if it is any faster. But if you are sure about the data format like line starting with the line number, followed by text, you can use regular expressions to get that entire line.

Comment: @Kira - to apply your RegExp you'd have to read and test the lines before. Splitting ReadAll on EOL may not without costs (time, memory), but you'd have random access.

Comment: @Edss `SkipLine` is your best. Use a database with an indexed table instead if its performance does not satisfy you. That's why databases exist.

Comment: Thanks guys for the ideas. After trying different solutions, like using schema or skipline. I've find it more reliable and faster using Readall, Split, and some loop. Thanks @Ekkehard.Horner

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of function that can did the trick for you :

```
Option Explicit
Dim Title,FromLine,ToLine,fso,Readfile,strBuff,InputFile,TotalNbLines
Title = "Extract Lines From TextFile"
InputFile = "c:\test.txt"
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set Readfile = Fso.OpenTextFile(InputFile,1)
strBuff = Readfile.ReadAll
TotalNbLines = Readfile.Line
Readfile.Close
'*******************************************************************************************************
MsgBox "The total number of lines in this file """& InputFile &""" = "& TotalNbLines,VbInformation,Title
'*******************************************************************************************************
MsgBox "Extract the 3 last lines" & vbcrlf & vbcrlf &_
ExtractLinesFromTextFile(InputFile,TotalNbLines - 2,TotalNbLines),64,Title 'To extract the 3 last lines
'*******************************************************************************************************
MsgBox "Extract line from line 1 to 2" & vbcrlf & vbcrlf &_
ExtractLinesFromTextFile(InputFile,1,2),64,Title 'Extract line from line 1 to 2
'*******************************************************************************************************
MsgBox "Extract line N°2" & vbcrlf & vbcrlf &_
ExtractLinesFromTextFile(InputFile,2,2),64,Title 'Extract line N°2
 '*******************************************************************************************************
MsgBox "Extract line from line 1 to 5" & vbcrlf & vbcrlf &_
ExtractLinesFromTextFile(InputFile,1,5),64,Title 'Extract line from line 1 to 5
 '*******************************************************************************************************
MsgBox "Extract line from line 1 to 10" & vbcrlf & vbcrlf &_
ExtractLinesFromTextFile(InputFile,1,10),64,Title'Extract line from line 1 to 10
 '*******************************************************************************************************
MsgBox "Extract line N° 12" & vbcrlf & vbcrlf &_
ExtractLinesFromTextFile(InputFile,12,12),64,Title'Extract line N° 12
'*********************************************************************************************************
Public Function ExtractLinesFromTextFile(ByRef TextFile, ByRef FromLine, ByRef ToLine) '<-- Inclusive
    Const TristateUseDefault = -2 'To Open the file using the system default.
    On Error Resume Next
    If FromLine <= ToLine Then
        With CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject").OpenTextFile(TextFile,1,true,TristateUseDefault)
            If Err.number <> 0 Then
                MsgBox err.description,16,err.description
                Exit Function
            Else
                Do Until .Line = FromLine Or .AtEndOfStream
                    .SkipLine
                Loop
                Do Until .Line > ToLine Or .AtEndOfStream
                    ExtractLinesFromTextFile = ExtractLinesFromTextFile & (.ReadLine & vbNewLine)
                Loop
            End If
        End With
    Else
        MsgBox "Error to Read Line in TextFile", vbCritical,"Error to Read Line in TextFile"
    End If
End Function
'*********************************************************************************************************
```